# Spring boot with Hibernate search - Index not created on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, hibernate-search

The index is created on the local file directory and not on the elasticsearch server.

I created a new spring boot project that for databased used spring-data along with hibernate search - https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-data/tree/master/es-hibernate-search-seperate

Its a simple CRUD operation. I am using mysql as backend and elasticsearch-5.6.3. The elasticsearch is running on the default configurations

The data is getting saved in mysql but the index is not created on the elasticsearch server. It is getting created in a file where I am running the project

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve this problem? I'm experiencing exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the Elasticsearch integration as the default for all indexes. By default Hibernate Search uses the embedded Lucene integration.

Just set the `hibernate.search.default.indexmanager` property to `elasticsearch`, either in `hibernate.properties` or in `persistence.xml`.

See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration-configuration) for details about Elasticsearch-specific configuration.